# View or empty rubbish bin of other volume?

Tags: apfs, trash, disk-volume

I would like to open (and empty) the Bin on a different volume.

It is an APFS volume.

I have tried looking in `/Volumes/other/.Trashes/` and `/Volumes/other/Users/sam/.Trash/`, but these locations don't seem to exist.

Comment: I'd expect deleted files on an "other" volume (more specifically: one other than the one that holds the home folder of the user that deleted the files) to be in /Volumes/other/.Trashes/[UserIDNumber]. Can you see the file(s) in the trash in Finder, and if so does Get Info show their location? More info might help, like what version of MacOS are you using; is there more than one system and/or user account involved; is the volume where the files are in the same APFS container as the system, same disk different container, or different disk, etc.

Comment: I can't see the files in the trash Bin in Finder. Using Catalina and the other volume is the boot volume of a Mojave installation, on a different disk.

Comment: Were the files thrown in the trash when it was booted from that Mojave volume? If so, look in the Mojave user's home folder for a .Trash folder.